# How to terminate a circuit

Tags: wiring

I am wiring a Sub Panel to an area near my 5th wheel approx. 100' distant.
I have read that I can terminate the circuits in two ways.

1. Sub Panel to a pedestal.
2. Sub Panel to an electrical receptacle secured to a post.

Is one way more prudent than the other?

Comment: [Power outlet panels](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/39692/33) are a common solution for hooking up RVs.

Comment: if it is on your property and you have room in your pannel why add a sub? havent put any in for a few years the 30A 110v were regulary fed with #10 to a outdoor rated outlet, the 50A 220v were usually set with a sub but that was usually because the main pannel would have been overloaded but I know at least 1 house with a 200-225A main panel fed from there and it was cheaper, what service do you need

Answer (score 4):

As in the answers above, there are outdoor rated panels made specifically for RVs. The image below is just one example. You should choose the appropriate panel which is rated for the needs of your RV. If you are thinking of trading up to an even bigger RV in the future, you should take that into consideration as well.

[image: Outdoor Power Outlet]

These must be mounted to a fixed location such as on the outside of a building, or on a post/pedestal. The panel below will supply enough power for the entire RV, including the appliances.

Getting back to your original question, you could either use a panel mounted to a post, or a pedestal. The advantage to the pedestal is that it is directly buried in the ground and the installation is a little cleaner. If you don't mind the looks of a post with a conduit coming out of the ground to the box, then it would be a good idea to go with a post since the pedestal is more expensive.

Keep in mind that you should probably consult a licensed electrician for the actual hookup. The long distance from the panel will require a substantial feeder from the main panel. The run will also need to either use wire rated for direct burial and/or run inside of conduit. The sub panel will also need to have independent ground rods which would be driven into the ground near the panel as well.

There may also need to be additional modifications made to your main panel inside your house to make room for the additional circuit.

Comment: the outdoor panel you suggested is basically a sub panel.  I would prefer to mount a plug receptacle on a post.

Comment: @RICHO If you know what you want, why are you asking us?

Comment: @Tester, my way may not be the wisest (safety wise), so I am trying to get an opinion on which way to go.  I am aware of outdoor panels for RVs, but would like to go with pole mounted receptacles.  Can I do it or not?

Comment: @RICHO yes you can do exactly what you talking about. The wire and circuit breaker have to be good for 50 amps or whatever size the receptacle is. Attach it to a pressure treated 4x4 and you are good.

Comment: @Archon, thank you very much.  I didn't understand why it was such a difficult question.